# Consulta MySQL envolvendo informações de Profissão e Nota registrados em uma mesma coluna

Tags: mysql

Considere uma tabela com a seguinte estrutura: a coluna **inf_codigo_contrato** corresponde a uma chave estrangeira de um outra tabela. Trata-se de código de contratos. Cada contrato possui basicamente 4 registros nesta tabela em questão.

A coluna **inf_valor** registra os tipos de informação: Profissão, Endereço, Nome e Nota, sendo que cada informação é registrada separadamente nesta tabela. Desta forma, para saber a qual tipo se refere a informação gravada em inf_valor, há também a  coluna **inf_codigo_variavel**, que também se refere a uma chave estrangeira de outra tabela.

Por meio desta coluna (inf_codigo_variavel), é possível saber a qual tipo de informação o inf_valor se refere. Por exemplo, se inf_codigo_variavel=117, o inf_valor se refere a profissão. Se o inf_codigo_variavel=124, o inf_valor se refere a nota.

Sendo assim, estou querendo montar uma query que satisfaça algumas condições ao mesmo tempo, da seguinte forma:

Mostrar qual a quantidade de contratos que possuem Nota **Ótimo** tendo como profissão **Analista de Sistemas**.

Ficando da seguinte forma:
(inf_codigo_variavel) = 124 e (inf_valor)=Ótimo e, ao mesmo tempo
(inf_codigo_variavel) = 117 e (inf_valor)=Analista de Sistemas

Coloquei a tabela no http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/895e8c/1

Observe que há apenas 4 contratos nesta tabela (58,59,60,61). Como dito acima, cada contrato tem 4 registros, estando cada um apontando para um tipo de informação diferente.

Neste caso, a consulta tem que retornar apenas 1 contrato, pois somente o contrato com código 58 que satisfaz a essa condição.

Comment: Só pra trazer a contagem total das ocorrência dessas duas condições?? Em uma unica linha?

Comment: Isso mesmo, Tmilitino

Comment: Não estou conseguindo acessar o link. Acho que está com algum problema no site. nem o .com esta entrando

Comment: Realmente o serviço parece estar meio instável. Para mim voltou agora.

Comment: Esta frase: "Ficando da seguinte forma: (inf_codigo_variavel) = 124 e (inf_valor)=Ótimo e, ao mesmo tempo (inf_codigo_variavel) = 117 e (inf_valor)=Analista de Sistemas"  está difícil de entender. Como "ao mesmo tempo" este par de variáveis pode contar dados diferentes? Defina melhor o que quer dizer com "ao mesmo tempo".

Comment: Olá, anônimo. é porque, no caso, em vez de eu ter criado quatro colunas, sendo cada uma respectiva para um tipo de informação (profissao, nota, endereço e nome), eu resolvi criar uma tabela à parte para inclusão dos tipos de  informações. e então, neste tabela apresentada em questão, eu acrescentei todas essas 4 informações em uma mesma coluna, sendo que cada registro irá especificar em uma coluna separada qual o tipo relacionado à informação. Por isso, estou com dificuldade em tratar duas condições ao considerar esse tipo de estrutura.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi é para retornar  ou `inf_codigo_variavel=124` e `inf_valor=Ótimo`  Ou (inf_codigo_variavel) = 117 e (inf_valor)=Analista de Sistemas, que no seu exemplo do link seria 4 linha que obedecem essa condição.a query que usei foi essa `select * from tabela where (inf_codigo_variavel=117 and inf_valor="Analista de Sistemas") or  (inf_codigo_variavel=124 and inf_valor="Ótimo")` e me retornou as 4 linhas.

Comment: Na verdade, Tmilitino,  a query tem que buscar os contratos cuja nota=Otimo e Profissão=Analista de Sistemas. Acompanhe a tabela pelo link acima. Veja que o resultado deveria ser 1, pois só há um contrato (inf_codigo_contrato=58) que satisfaz a essa condição.

Comment: tem que ter o mesmo contrato? e você quer saber quantos obedecem essa condição né?

Comment: Isso, veja que há quatro contratos no total (58,59,60,61), e cada um deles possui 4 registros, cada registro correspondendo a um tipo de informação

Comment: Por favor coloque isso na pergunta, vai ficar mais claro pra todos.

Comment: vou fazer isso.

Comment: Não seria o caso de repensar seu modelo de dados?

Comment: Entao, essa estrutura foi pensada a fim de atender a criação dinamica de tipos de informação.

Comment: Talvez o MySQL não seja o SGBD mais apropriado para implantar um banco de dados chave-valor. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-value_database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de varias forma uma delas é criando duas subtabelas uma que obedeça a 1º condição e outra que obedeça a 2º condição. como no exemplo abaixo.

```
select count(otimo.inf_codigo_contrato) from 
(select inf_codigo_contrato from tabela where inf_codigo_variavel=117 and inf_valor="Analista de Sistemas") as anSistema 
inner join 
(select inf_codigo_contrato from tabela where inf_codigo_variavel=124 and inf_valor="Ótimo") as otimo 
on anSistema.inf_codigo_contrato=otimo.inf_codigo_contrato
```

Outra opção seria utilizando `functions`, ai você vai escolher a melhor para o seu caso, ver questão de desempenho e tudo mais.

Comment: vou testar e retorno =D

Comment: Deu certíssimo Tmilitino.. Vou marcar a sua resposta para essa pergunta.. Agradeço muito o suporte!

Comment: Só fique atento para o desempenho da consulta no banco, isso é primordial

Comment: vou monitorar isso. Muito obrigado, amigo.

Answer (score 2):

Se eu entendi corretamente:

```
SELECT count(inf_codigo_contrato) FROM sua_tabela
WHERE (inf_codigo_variavel=117 AND inf_valor='ANALISTA DE SISTEMAS') OR (inf_codigo_variavel=124 AND inf_valor='OTIMO');
```

Com suas novas explicações talvez esta query atenda:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT inf_codigo_contrato) FROM sua_tabela
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sua_tabela WHERE inf_codigo_variavel=117 AND inf_valor='ANALISTA DE SISTEMAS') AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sua_tabela WHERE inf_codigo_variavel=124 AND inf_valor='OTIMO');
```

Realmente ficou incompleta.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT inf_codigo_contrato) FROM sua_tabela A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sua_tabela B WHERE A.inf_codigo_contrato=B.inf_codigo_contrato AND B.inf_codigo_variavel=117 AND B.inf_valor='ANALISTA DE SISTEMAS') AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sua_tabela C WHERE A.inf_codigo_contrato=C.inf_codigo_contrato AND C.inf_codigo_variavel=124 AND C.inf_valor='OTIMO');
```

Comment: Já tentou essa? deu algum erro?

Comment: Refiz a minha pergunta de uma outra maneira. Ela agora está mais explicativa e detalhada.

Comment: vou testar aqui, anonimo, e volto para dar o feedback.

Comment: ele retornou 4 :(

Answer (score 2):

Pode tentar esta solução, acredito que você precisa de dois selects para fazer isto, um para cada condição.

```
    SELECT count(t.inf_codigo_contrato) FROM tabela AS t
     WHERE t.inf_codigo_variavel=117 
       AND t.inf_valor='ANALISTA DE SISTEMAS'
       AND t.inf_codigo_contrato IN (
           SELECT inf_codigo_contrato 
             FROM tabela
            WHERE  inf_codigo_variavel=124 
              AND inf_valor='OTIMO'
)
```

Comment: vou testar agora pra ver.

Comment: Mto obrigado Rafael! Deu certo aqui!

Answer (score 1):

Segue consulta:

```
 SELECT count(*) as qtd_otimo
            FROM tabela t1
                INNER JOIN tabela t2 ON t2.inf_codigo_contrato = t1.inf_codigo_contrato
            WHERE
                t1.inf_codigo_variavel = 117
                AND t1.inf_valor='ANALISTA DE SISTEMAS'
                AND t2.inf_codigo_variavel = 124
                AND t2.inf_valor = 'Ótimo'
            GROUP BY t1.inf_codigo_contrato
```

Comment: Mto obrigado João. testei tambem aqui a sua query, funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado a todos.